# How do I assign the current user Id to a newly created object in React/Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

How would I assign the id of the current user to a newly created object? I've tested the server and it seems to be working as I intend on the back-end so it must be an issue with my React/Redux flow.

I'm currently assigning the userId in submit handler on the form then passing it to the action and reducer. I've copied my code here for clarification.

**Submit handler when for when a new object gets created**

```
  handleOnSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    let newTeam = Object.assign({}, this.props.teamFormData, {
      author: this.props.auth.user.userId
    });
    this.props.createTeam(newTeam);
  };
```

**Action**

```
export const createTeam = team => {
  return dispatch => {
    return fetch(`${API_URL}/teams`, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(team)
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(team => {
        dispatch(addTeam(team));
        dispatch(resetTeamForm());
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  };
};
```

**Reducer**

```
    case "CREATE_TEAM_SUCCESS":
      return state.concat(action.teams);
```

Somewhere along this flow, my object assign for userId starting from the React component is failing. Should I be thinking about doing this differently?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, it looks like you're relatively new to the site. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and ask yourself if all of that code and markup is really necessary to reproduce the issue. Thank you!

Comment: log `newTeam` to console before calling `this.props.createTeam` to confirm is has what you expect. Also might want to mention exactly where the author prop is not being set where you expect it to. ie is it missing from the redux store, in the database server-side, or something else?

Comment: `newTeam` is logging exactly what I want it to log. I expect the author prop to be assigned automatically without having to assign it. Right now I'm losing the author object assign at the action part of Redux.